# Is WebComponent.removed() ever called?

Tags: dart, dart-webui, polymer

After overriding three lifecycle methods of `WebComponent`: `created()`, `inserted()`, and `removed()`, I can see that the first two are called consistently but `removed()` is never called.  Is there anything special that needs to be done so that `removed()` is called?  Or is it simply never called?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `removed()` method is called when a custom element is removed from the DOM. Here is a small program that demonstrates the use of the `created()`, `inserted()`, and `removed()` lifecycle events.

Create a Dart web application with an `index.html` file that looks like this:

```dart
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <title>index</title>
    <link rel="import" href="my_element.html">
    <script src="packages/polymer/boot.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id='container'><my-element></my-element></div>
    <script type="application/dart">
      import 'dart:html';
      void main() {
        query('#container').onClick.listen((event) {
          event.target.remove();
        });
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This file imports and displays a custom element, `<my-element>`.

Define the following file that defines `<my-element>`:

```dart
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <body>
    <polymer-element name="my-element">
      <template>
        <p>The name is {{person.name}}</p>
      </template>

      <script type="application/dart" src="my_element.dart"></script>
    </polymer-element>
  </body>
</html>
```

And define the accompanying Dart file that demonstrates the lifecycle methods getting called:

```dart
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';

class Person extends Object with ObservableMixin {
  @observable String name;
  Person(this.name);
}

@CustomTag("my-element")
class MyElement extends PolymerElement {
  @observable Person person = new Person('Shailen');

  void created() {
    super.created();
    print('created');
  }

  void inserted() {
    print('inserted');
  }

  void removed() {
    print('removed');
  }
}
```

When you run `index.html`, you will see a paragraph with some text in it. The `created()` and `inserted()` lifecycle methods are called, and 'created' and 'inserted' messages print in the console. When you click on the div that contains the custom element, the element is removed, the `removed()` lifecycle method is called, and 'removed' prints in the console.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help!  Unfortunately I was not precise in my question.  I do not remove components explicitly but instead use conditional templates to instantiate components.  I also do not use polymer libraries yet.  Considering how I asked the question I have to vote your answer as the correct one.  I will migrate to polymer libraries ASAP, may be this migration will fix my current problems.  Thank you again for your time!